# struts2 extenalization

Tags: struts2

I'm using struts2 in my jsp.

I need to externalize my labels in jsp into a properties file.

Can anyone tell me how to externalize the label names in properties file in struts2.

Any examples will help lot.

Answer (score 1):

This page from the official beginners tutorial explains how to do it and has examples:

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/message-resource-files.html

Be sure to go through the rest of the tutorial.  It is the best place to start when learning Struts2.